# CodePipeline CloudFormation Template configuration

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to use the CloudFormation Template configuration field in a CodePipeline. If you edit the CloudFormation in CodePipeline it looks like this:

[image]

If my `InputArtifactName` is `MyAppBuild` and I have a CloudFormation config file in `cfg-prd.json`, my hope was I could enter `MyAppBuild::cfg-prd.json` and have it pick it up.

I get an error about the template file not being valid even though it works manually as:

```
--parameters cfg-prd.json
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that the [Template Configuration File](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-cfn-artifacts.html#d0e10167) has a different JSON structure than the format accepted by the `--parameters` option to [`aws cloudformation create-stack`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html#options):

```
{
  "Parameters" : {
    "NameOfTemplateParameter" : "ValueOfParameter",
    ...
  },
  "StackPolicy" : {
    "Statement" : [
      StackPolicyStatement
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: wjordan strikes again! - Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

A nice trick to see what the Cloudformation layout should be is to create a pipeline which you know will work. Then use the CLI to extract a cloudformation template.

```
aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name <pipelinename>
```

You will get the JSON of the Codepipeline resource. There will be a few changes required but from this you can see exactly what the syntax should be and from there parameterised your template and create Codepipelines programatically.

Comment: Does not answer what is being asked!

Comment: actually it provides the means to get the exact cloudformation template and figure out how the template file is referenced.